# Malicious actors on LAN

Tags: server, lan

I was reading [this security advise](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim/blob/master/SECURITY.md#malicious-actors-on-lan), which says:

> The neovim process binds itself to 127.0.0.1, so malicious actors on your LAN should be **unable** to interact with either your webextension or your neovim process.

There is a typo there, as "unable" should be "able", right?

Comment: This is a networking question, not a security question: "why can't a node on the LAN access another node's loopback address?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the IP address for the [loopback interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) on a system. It is only reachable from the system itself and not from outside the system, including not reachable from the LAN. So there is no typo here.